# Prevent page from scrolling when page elements are removed

Tags: javascript, html

I have a bunch of divs that i am removing from the document using javascript. When this is done, the length of the page is often shortened significantly, and if the user had scrolled down the page, it gets abruptly recentered because the entire page now fits on the window.

This causes the user to no longer have their mouse over the same buttons on the page. I'd like to prevent this auto scrolling, but it seems like it may be difficult. I admit that it doesn't make much sense to allow a page to be scrolled off of its contents. Seems like the best I could do is to leave dummy divs as placeholders. Once the user scrolls back up, then clean them up to shrink the page.

Are there other, cleaner solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just set the divs to be removed to *visibility: hidden* (add a class or similar) so they still take up room in the document. At a suitable time you actually remove them and allow the document to reflow.